# iOS CoreGraphic Draw Triangle With Gradient

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am going to draw a Triangle in UIView with gradient.
Gradient must be from one line to the opposite side.
And I have to draw serveral triangles.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Please specify objective-c or swift. and format your question and add some code that what you have tried so far? :)

Comment: It is Objective C. Have you tried one?